# Keeping napthalene balls in computer cabinet to prevent spiders

Tags: cleaning

Would naphthalene balls help prevent spiders from living in computer cabinet?
If won't, what would be helpful.

Also, there's dust in it, how can I prevent it too?

Comment: You can't really prevent dust inside it unless it's in a 'clean room'. It has a cooling fan which draws in air from the room. My solution is to clean inside the cabinet every so often, using a [small hoover attachment](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Universal-Micro-Vacuum-Cleaner-Attachment/dp/B01BMHS330).

Comment: Yes, naphthalene is used as an insect repellent which would also work for spiders. You could construct a filter which would reduce but not eliminate dust.

Comment: Thank you both of you @WeatherVane and Stan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible naphthalene (or p-dichlorobenzene, which is often used instead for "mothflakes") may have a deleterious effect on some components of the PC. Some HDD's, for example, "breathe" through a dust filter to accommodate changes in internal or external air pressure with heat or altitude. If the vapors pass the filter, it could shorten the life of the drive.

As mentioned, cleaning, and keeping the PC in a fairly clean location, are the safe options. You might remove the PC, apply insecticide or repellent in the are *around* where the PC sits, and then put it back when dust has settled.

Comment: Even I was thinking if it could burn my computer if "Naphthalenes" are inflammable.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Plastics absorb the mothball smell https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/181284/naphthalene-absorbed-by-hdpe so expect your computer will in turn stink up wherever you later put it.